# jQuery: Finish one function before executing other commands

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a slightly complex jQuery code, using a form.submit upon navigation of tabs. I have a form on every tab. The form.submit invokes an ajax request and returns isValid (a variable indicating if the form has been validated or not). Following this, I want to cease navigation from the tab if the data entered is invalid.

My Jquery code goes a bit like this:

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.tab', '.nav-pills a', function (e) {

    $('#form').submit(); //invokes the submit function
    return isValid; //form.submit alters the value for this
});
```

My isValid is a global variable.

```
var isValid=true;

$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
     //does an ajax request, and sets isValid to be true if form validation
     //at back end is successful. Otherwise it's false
}
```

However, it seems jQuery is executing the return statement before the form.submit function.

If I alert isValid in $(document).on('hide.bs.tab', '.nav-pills a', function (e), I get a true even if the form isn't valid, while at the same time if there is an alert statement for isValid in form.submit it gives me false/true correctly.

I've read this has something to do with delaying but I do not know how to work with it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**POTENTIAL SOLUTION**

**so after doing some research, I made the property of asyncrhonous to false in the ajax request, and it started working exactly as expected but is this the correct approach?**

Comment: in that case you have to return from form submit event

Comment: this is because ajax is asynchronous. If you want something not to run until the ajax has completed, you have to run that code inside the ajax callback

Comment: @ADyson so inside the success function, if validation is confirmed, I would do return isValid?

Comment: try this : $("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {

         // tasks to do 


   });

Comment: @kanzari yea that was my first attempt, but it does not seem to work either. Is there any way to make jquery completely finish the form.submit function before doing the return statement?

Comment: humm, try this other method then : $("#form").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
      var $form = $( this ),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
      var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), name2: $('#name2').val() } );

      /* Alerts the results */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
      });
    });

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this approach :

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
      var $form = $( this ),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
      var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), name2: $('#name2').val() } );

      /* Alerts the results */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
      });
    });
```

Hope it's help,

Comment: nope, it does not display any error. But it doesn't do anything either. I found a partial working solution but I don't know if that is the correct approach.